# REST API POST request and Response

Tags: java, rest, jersey, spring-restcontroller

I am working on REST API,i have a request

```
 <User>
       <firstname>aaa</firstname>
       <middlename>bbb</middlename>
       <lastname>ccc</lastname>
       <age>25</age>
       <dob>01021988</dob>
       <address>bangalore</address>
    </User>
```

and i am able to persist data successfully and created user.

but i want my request to be like below ,i want to send fname,mname,lname as attributes of user element.I want to tell client xml is invalid if the xml request coming is not like below

```
<User firstname="aaa" middlename="bbb" lastname="ccc">
     <age>25</age>
     <dob>01021988</dob>
     <address>bangalore</address>
 </User>
```

1-- and also i am even more concerned about order of attributes and elements.

Comment: Any inputs on this plz

Comment: Any suggestions for this plz